# How to find and replace in a regex code

Tags: regex

I am trying to find and replace in a regex code

```
<div class="gallery-image-container">
    <div jstcache="1116"
         class="gallery-image-high-res loaded"
         style="width: 396px;
                height: 264px;
                background-image: url(&quot;https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipMcTfMPZj_d5iip9WKtN2SQB9Je5U4rRB0nT_t8=s396-k-no&quot;);
                background-size: 396px 264px;"
         jsan="7.gallery-image-high-res,7.loaded,5.width,5.height,5.background-image,5.background-size">
    </div>
</div>
```

In the code above I used This

```
(https:\/\/[^&]*)
```

To extract this URL

```
https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipMcTfMPZj_d5iip9WKtN2SQB9Je5U4rRB0nT_t8=s396-k-no
```

I used This regex `s\d{3}` to get `s396`

Now I want to replace `s396` to `s1000` in the URL

Now am Stock and don't know how to go about it.

Please is there anyway all these can be done in just one regex code not multiple codes?

Comment: Try to avoid using regex to parse HTML content.

Comment: I am trying to use it to collect data

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using an HTML parser, but I understand sometimes that is not possible.  Here is a little example in python.

```
import re

data = '''
<div class="gallery-image-container">
    <div jstcache="1116"
         class="gallery-image-high-res loaded"
         style="width: 396px;
            height: 264px;
            background-image: url(&quot;https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipMcTfMPZj_d5iip9WKtN2SQB9Je5U4rRB0nT_t8=s396-k-no&quot;);
            background-size: 396px 264px;"
         jsan="7.gallery-image-high-res,7.loaded,5.width,5.height,5.background-image,5.background-size">
    </div>
</div>
'''
match = re.search("(https?://[^&]+)", data)
url = match.group(1)
url = re.sub("s\d{3}", "s1000", url)
print(url)
```

They key part is the regex of

```
(https?://[^&]+)
```

It is using a negative character class.  It's saying, look for `http` with an optional `s` followed by `://` and then all the *non* `&`  You can use this site to play around with regexs:

https://regex101.com/r/b0APFA/1

I'm sure you could do a clever 1 liner nested regex to find and replace all at once, but it's going to be easier to troubleshoot if you have a few lines.

Comment: Thanks but I still need to replace `s396` with `s1000`

Comment: @ChijiokeObi I have added that in now :)

Comment: Thanks but am not working with python and it's still hard for me get it right